# Pagination Not Working Properly

Tags: pagination

Whenever I insert a page break it doesn't translate to the published blog article. Instead, the article stops where the first page break was inserted. No navigation appears to guide the reader to the second page. I have tried using the short cut to enter the code and the manual way. Both ways the break physically appears but when the blog piece is published, the same thing happens.

Suggestions?

Comment: are you referring to https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links ?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your theme. If so, contact the theme's authors for support. Try switching to a bundled theme and see if the issue persists. If it does, disable all plugins and enable them one by one to find the culprit. Then contact the plugin's authors for support. Third party plugins and themes are out of scope here on WPSE.

Answer (score 0):

IF you a using a query post make sure to add

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }
query_posts( 'post_type=yourposttype&paged='.$paged);
```

above script will correct the dead links on wordpress pagination.